# How to use AND to apply two conditions in an If statement?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to move emails from **Inprogress Folder** to **Completed Folder**, based on the word placed in the body of the mail when replied to.

1. if the reply mail has the word **Completed** then the reply mails have to be moved to **Completed Folder**.
2. if the reply mail has the word **Cancelled** then the reply mails have to be moved to  **Cancelled Folder**.

I tried the below code, but it throws

> Compile Error: Excepted expression

**Error is because of this two-line.**

```
If InStr(1,olMail.Body, "Completed") And
If InStr(1, Item.Subject, olObj.Subject) > 0
```

**Full Code:**

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim olNameSpace As NameSpace
    Set olNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim olDestFolder As folder
    Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("Completed")
    
    Dim olLookUpFolder As folder
    Set olLookUpFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("InProgress")

    ' olMail is a Class. Avoid as a variable name
    'Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olObj As Object ' Outlook items are not necessarily mailitems
    
    For Each olObj In olLookUpFolder.Items 'loop through Tickets folder to find original mail
    
        If olObj.Class = olMail Then

            If InStr(1,olMail.Body, "Completed") And
            If InStr(1, Item.Subject, olObj.Subject) > 0  Then 'look for olObj.Subject in Item.Subject

                olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                Exit For
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to write

```
If InStr(1,olMail.Body, "Completed") > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Subject, olObj.Subject) > 0 Then 'look for olObj.Subject in Item.Subject

       olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
       Exit For
End If
```

Comment: Nope, It's not working. If I replaced with above code its throws **Run-time error '91'object variable or With block variable not set**

Comment: @SrinevasanDhandapani There is no `olMail` object. See the comment in the question. **olMail is a Class. Avoid as a variable name** which is why there is `olObj`.

Comment: I believe the object required is `Item`.